# Splitting list of dictionary into sublists after the occurence of particular key of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries. These dictionaries basically have just one key-value each.

For example:

```
lst = [{'x': 23}, {'y': 23432}, {'z': 78451}, {'a': 564}, {'x': 45},
       {'y': 7546}, {'a': 4564}, {'x': 54568}, {'y': 4515}, {'z': 78457}, 
       {'b': 5467}, {'a': 784}]
```

I am trying to divide the list of dictionaries `lst` into sublists after every occurrence of a dictionary with a specific key `"a"`.

I tried using other ways that I saw on the internet but as I am new to python, I am not able to understand them and get the desired result. I want the final result to look like:

```
final_lst = [
    [{'x': 23}, {'y': 23432}, {'z': 78451}, {'a': 564}],
    [{'x': 45}, {'y': 7546}, {'a': 4564}],
    [{'x': 54568}, {'y': 4515}, {'z': 78457}, {'b': 5467}, {'a': 784}]],
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a generator that collects elements and yields when the condition is met:

```
def split_by_key(lst, key):
    collected = []
    for d in lst:
        collected.append(d)
        if key in d:
            yield collected
            collected = []
    if collected:  # yield any remainder
        yield collected

final_lst = list(split_by_key(lst, 'a'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [{'x': 23}, {'y': 23432}, {'z': 78451}, {'a': 564}, {'x': 45},
...        {'y': 7546}, {'a': 4564}, {'x': 54568}, {'y': 4515}, {'z': 78457},
...        {'b': 5467}, {'a': 784}]
>>> list(split_by_key(lst, 'a'))
[[{'x': 23}, {'y': 23432}, {'z': 78451}, {'a': 564}], [{'x': 45}, {'y': 7546}, {'a': 4564}], [{'x': 54568}, {'y': 4515}, {'z': 78457}, {'b': 5467}, {'a': 784}]]
>>> pprint(_)
[[{'x': 23}, {'y': 23432}, {'z': 78451}, {'a': 564}],
 [{'x': 45}, {'y': 7546}, {'a': 4564}],
 [{'x': 54568}, {'y': 4515}, {'z': 78457}, {'b': 5467}, {'a': 784}]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir......i appreciate the help...it works as i wanted it to work!!! @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straightforward solution:

```
result = []

for item in lst:
    if not result or 'a' in result[-1][-1]:
        result.append([])

    result[-1].append(item)
```

Comment: Please do include an explanation of the code, don't just dump something here without telling **why** this works.

Comment: Caveat: if `lst` is empty, this results in a list with a single empty list contained in it.

Comment: @DanilSperansky: I do explain, briefly, what the code does. When I posted my comment, all you had was code and nothing else, then edited to say 'try'. Why not just say *Append to the last nested list, and add a new nested list every time the condition is met* or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `itertools.groupby`.

```
import itertools

lst2 = []
for i, (_, g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: not x.keys() - {'a'})):
     if not i % 2:
        lst2.append([])
     lst2[-1].extend(list(g))
```

---

```
lst2 
[[{'x': 23}, {'y': 23432}, {'z': 78451}, {'a': 564}],
 [{'x': 45}, {'y': 7546}, {'a': 4564}],
 [{'x': 54568}, {'y': 4515}, {'z': 78457}, {'b': 5467}, {'a': 784}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` together pairs of delimiting indexes of each partition from a conditional comprehension. Then you comprehend the appropriate slices:

```
splits = [i for i, d in enumerate(lst, 1) if 'a' in d]
final_lst = [lst[start: end] for start, end in zip([0] + splits, splits)]
# final_lst
# [[{'x': 23}, {'y': 23432}, {'z': 78451}, {'a': 564}], [{'x': 45}, {'y': 7546}, {'a': 4564}], [{'x': 54568}, {'y': 4515}, {'z': 78457}, {'b': 5467}, {'a': 784}]]
```

Docs on [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to bunch, this would be solution based on `x` instead of `a`:

```
lst = [{'x':23}, {'y':23432}, {'z':78451}, {'a':564}, {'x':45}, {'y':7546},
       {'a':4564}, {'x':54568}, {'y':4515}, {'z':78457}, {'b':5467}, {'a':784}]

result = []
temp = []

breaker = 'x'

for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    if item.keys() != [breaker]:  
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        if i == 0:
            temp.append(item)
        else:
            result.append(temp)
            temp = [item]
    if i == len(lst)-1:
        result.append(temp)
```